# "Incomplete" object instantiation and output behavior

Tags: c++, c++17

How does the following code exactly work?

```
#include <cstdio>

template<class T>
T x = T{};

void foo()
{
    class Test
    {
    public:
        Test() { std::printf("Test::Test\n"); }
    };

    Test t = x<Test>;
}


int main()
{
    std::printf("main\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
Test::Test
main
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a68c77a184220b5)

- Why does it print `Test::Test` first instead of `main`?
- Which standard it relies on? Is it C++1z only? I can't find the related proposal. Could you give me a link?
- What is `x` in this code and how does `Test t = x<Test>` assignment actually work?

Moreover, if I change `std::printf` calls to `std::cout` the whole program crashes:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
T x = T{};

void foo()
{
    class Test
    {
    public:
        Test() { std::cout << "Test::Test\n"; }
    };

    Test t = x<Test>;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "main\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c20353f4224bfb7b)

Why?

Comment: Google "variable template".

Comment: @sleep tight pupper Ok, thanks. Why does it instantiated w/o call to the `foo` function then?

Comment: [tmp.inst/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#variable%20template!definition~of): "Unless a variable template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the variable template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is used"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned already, you used a variable template.

If I'm not mistaken, variable templates are analogous to something like this:

```
template<class T>
struct X {
    static T x;
};

template<class T>
T X<T>::x = T{};
```

You then use it, which would be something like:

```
void foo() {
    class Test {
    public:
        Test() { std::printf("Test::Test\n"); }
    };

    Test t = X<Test>::x;
}
```

If you try this, you will see the same result: [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9acb431282dde60).

The template is instantiated in `foo`, and code to initialize the static member is emitted.
This initialization happens before `main` runs, so you see `Test::Test` printed first.

As for the initialization happening despite the code where the variable is used never being called - I *suppose* the compiler could try to reason about `foo` never being called in the entire program, `Test` being a local class whose type does not escape `foo`, thus making the instantiation `X<Test>::x` unreachable for anyone else, and decide to remove it...

...but I imagine this would require some effort at link time, and I don't see this behavior mandated by the standard.

Also, I'm not sure if the compiler/linker is even allowed to remove the initialization of non-local variables, if that initialization has side effects.